# How do I correctly loop through a NodeList from document.querySelectorAll()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

In an exercise to learn about different AJAX requests I want to apply a fade transition on my `#quote` every time a button is clicked. *(The fade effect is not part of the exercise, it is just something I added on my own behalf)*

[**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/SirExotic/pen/jKWWbX)

I know how to do this when there is one button (or just the first button) with `document.querySelector()`, but I learned that `document.querySelectorAll()` returns a static NodeList in the form of an array and you will need to loop through the array to do something with each button.

I have tried a few things, but I can't figure it out.

This is what I have so far, and as far as I understand these 2 bits of code need to be inside each other, and my question is *how*.

```
// Quote animation
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

[].forEach.call(buttons, function(button){
  // quote should have .fade applied every time one of the four buttons is clicked
});

$(button).addEventListener("click", function(){
    $(quote).addClass("fade");
    $(quote).bind('oanimationend animationend webkitAnimationEnd', function(){ 
        $(this).removeClass("fade");
    });
})
```

Comment: Why `.querySelectorAll()` and `.addEventListener()` if there's jQuery available? And `.addEventListener()` won't work with a jQuery object.

Comment: Perhaps I'm thinking about it the wrong way, can you help me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will select every button and trigger your fade effect

```
$("button").on('click', function(){
    $(quote).addClass("fade");
    $(quote).bind('oanimationend animationend webkitAnimationEnd', function(){ 
        $(this).removeClass("fade");
    });
});
```

Comment: Oh my god, now I see how silly I was. I was so focused on .addEventListener because of the AJAX requests that I totally forgot about the standard jQuery. Thanks.

Comment: Eventually I ended up with [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/XnMNKmv.png) and it works beautifully.